# Openshift nodeJS successful deployment, but got "Application is not available"

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have created simplest nodeJS app and it running locally, but not on OpenShift.

I use *Import from Git* and the code imported and build successfully.

When I click *Open URL* in my app, it show `"Application is not available"` page.

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello from Node.js Starter Application!');
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App started on PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
  }
}
```

The most last from logs:

```
> node index.js
App started on PORT 8000
```

What I have missed to successfully run my server on OpenShift?

Thank you

Comment: are you doing a npm install?

Comment: @Aditya_Anand seems it is doing automatically

Comment: What do you have in your services and routes? IIRC, the default newapp generation isn't expecting to expose port 800.